# How can I get URL from banner ad after clicked by user

Tags: android, webview, admob, banner-ads

I am creating an app in which I want that when the 
**user clicks on Banner ad,**(Normally it opens the default browser to handle the redirect process)

Instead of this,
It will not open any browser and  **only copy the link which is sent to default browser and open it inside my web view**.

I want to get the URL from the banner ad.
I had searched on google for it but unfortunately, I did not find anything useful.
Thank you all of you for my help in advance...:-)

Comment: Simple answer...you can't..! It is against their policies..

Answer (score 0):

This is against the terms of service of your adMob i guess. You can't access the url and open it yourself in webview. But i can suggest you to create your own activity and make it default browser in manifest. I think that will work for you.

Here is example how to do it.

add these filters inside `<activity></activity>` of your webview activity

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Firstly, I want to ask if i is not possible to get URL from banner ads than how some apps use this technique (like mCent Browser).

Comment: Secondly, these codes shows me Missing data element error in mainfest